# VBA change a activecell offset on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

To start off I have been learning much from this site thru out the years. Having said that I am still quite green when it comes to more complex lines of code. I will do my best to describe what I am trying to do and maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

I have TWO columns in a series like:

```
Column A             Column B
1                    0
1                    1
1                    2
1                    0
1                    1
1                    2
2                    0
2                    1
2                    2
4                    0
4                    1
```

What I would like to do is search column B till I get to the last number of the column A sequence then change column A number up by one. So my end result should be:

```
Column A             Column B
1                    0
1                    1
1                    2
2*                   0
2*                   1
2*                   2
3                    0
3                    1
3                    2
4                    0
4                    1
```

I tried to do something like

```
Sub pdiddy()`
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""`
  If ActiveCell.Value < 15 Then 'the column b sequence is only going to be between the numbers 0-15
     ActiveCell.offest(1, 0).Value 1  'the column A sequence can increase until 99
  End If
Loop
End Sub
```

I would like to keep the number in Column A if the number sequence does not go above 15, before it is changed.
I hope I have explained this clear. I want to make sure that there are NO Column A & B combinations that are the same. Thanks in advance everyone for helping newbies understand and get better at code sequences. Also I tried to code tag this but I don't think I did it right I apologies now.
BSOV

Comment: I think you accidentally accepted the wrong answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than make the previous answer unrecognizable, here is code that does what you asked for. For reference I produce the output (side by side with the original).

The code:

```
Sub pdiddy()
Dim bank, cue
Dim r As Range

Set r = Range("b2")              ' point to the first cell in column C: cueWrap
bank = Range("A2").Value - 1     ' starting value for bank ... code adds one in the first pass
cue = r.Value                    ' first value for cue
Do Until r.Value = ""
  r.Select
  If r.Value < r.Offset(-1, 0) Or r.Value >= 15 Then ' must wrap
    If r.Value > 15 Then cue = (r.Value Mod 15) Else cue = 0
    If r.Offset(0, -1) = r.Offset(-1, -1) Or cue = 0 Then
      bank = bank + 1
    End If
  Else
    cue = r.Value
  End If
  If bank > 127 Then Exit Do    ' 127 banks available
  If r.Offset(0, -1).Value > bank Then bank = r.Offset(0, -1).Value
  r.Offset(0, -1).Value = bank    ' overwrite bank
  r.Value = cue                   ' overwrite cue
  Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)          ' next cell down
Loop
End Sub
```

The output:

```
---after---     --- before ----
Bank    Cue     Bank    Cue
10        1     10  1
10        2     10  2
10        3     10  3
10        4     10  4
10        5     10  5
10        6     10  6
10        7     10  7
10        8     10  8
10        9     10  9
10       10     10  10
10       11     10  11
10       12     10  12
10       13     10  13
10       14     10  14
10       15     10  15
11        1     10  16
11        2     10  17
11        3     10  18
11        4     10  19
11        5     10  20
11        6     10  21
11        7     10  22
11        8     10  23
11        9     10  24
11       10     10  25
11       11     10  26
11       12     10  27
11       13     10  28
11       14     10  29
11       15     10  30
12        1     10  31
12        2     10  32
13        1     11  1
13        2     11  2
13        3     11  3
13        4     11  4
13        5     11  5
13        6     11  6
13        7     11  7
13        8     11  8
13        9     11  9
13       10     11  10
13       11     11  11
13       12     11  12
13       13     11  13
13       14     11  14
13       15     11  15
14        1     11  16
14        2     11  17
15        1     12  1
15        2     12  2
15        3     12  3
15        4     12  4
15        5     12  5
15        6     12  6
15        7     12  7
15        8     12  8
15        9     12  9
15       10     12  10
15       11     12  11
15       12     12  12
15       13     12  13
15       14     12  14
15       15     12  15
16        1     12  16
16        2     12  17
16        3     12  18
16        4     12  19
16        5     12  20
16        6     12  21
16        7     12  22
16        8     12  23
16        9     12  24
16       10     12  25
16       11     12  26
16       12     12  27
16       13     12  28
16       14     12  29
16       15     12  30
17        1     12  31
17        2     12  32
21        1     21  1
21        2     21  2
21        3     21  3
21        4     21  4
21        5     21  5
21        6     21  6
21        7     21  7
21        8     21  8
21        9     21  9
```

Comment: This was very close I miss spoke about the sequence. It is 0-14 not 1-15. I tried to modify the code but it still adds a 1 to the zero spot.

Comment: I modified the code (but not the output...) - can't test the output at this instant but I believe this should map the cue to 0-14 instead of 1-15.

Comment: I removed the +1 after `cue = (r.Value Mod 15)` that seems to fix it. great solution. I am trying to decompile it and understand how to have so many if scenarios. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little bit unclear; I am going to answer the question I think you are trying to ask: "Whenever the sequence in B 'resets', I want to increment the corresponding number in column A by one".

```
Sub pdiddy()
Dim Aval, Bval
Dim r as Range

Set r = Range("B1") ' point to the first cell in column B
Aval = 1            ' starting value for A
Bval = r.Value
Do Until r.Value = ""            ' <<<< edited
  If r.Value < Bval Then         ' sequence wraps
    Aval = Aval + 1              ' increment A
    if Aval > 99 Then Exit Do    ' "column A sequence can increase until 99"
  End If
  r.offset(0, -1).Value = Aval   ' set the value in the column to the left
  Bval = r.Value                 ' <<<< added
  set r = r.Offset(1,0)          ' next cell down
Loop
End Sub
```

if that doesn't do what you intended, please clarify in the comments. In particular it was not clear from your question what action should be taken when something (A, B?) reaches the value of `15`.

Comment: I see I was not too clear about the 15 part. Before I get into that the above code you supplied I cannot get to work. I get a sub or function not defined form the THEN BREAK part.

Comment: Ok now I can step thru the code but I don't see anything change. So I am going to try to explain this again with a bit more code so we can see where I am going wrong. please bare with me it is important to see the why the sequence is important to retain its original numbers when possible.

Comment: I am trying to convert a list of audio cues from one format into another. The original format will alow up to 99 banks(column A) and 32 cues (column B). The new format I am converting to will only allow 127 banks (new Column A) and 16 cues (new Column B). The real trick is making sure there are no duplicates, I will be using CONCATENATE to create a unique name out of the two columns. So on to the code and examples

Comment: `Sub pdiddy()`

`Worksheets("sheet6").Range("A2").Select`
`Call RollbackNumbers`
`Worksheets("sheet6").Range("B2").Select`
`Call RollbackNumbers`
`Worksheets("sheet6").Range("B2").Select`
`Call Cue32Cue16`


`'here is where it needs to now look and make sure there are no duplicates if so it needs to increase the bank # for that whole sequnce by one`

`End Sub`

Comment: `Sub RollbackNumbers()

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value - 1
        ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop
End Sub




`

Comment: Sub Cue32Cue16()
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        If ActiveCell.Value < 16 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 31 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 15
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 30 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 14
ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 29 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 13
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 28 Then

Comment: ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 12
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 27 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 11
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 26 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 10
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 25 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 9
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 24 Then

Comment: ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 8
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 23 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 7
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 22 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 6
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 21 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 5
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 20 Then

Comment: ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 4
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 19 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 3
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 18 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 2

Comment: ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 17 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 1
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = 16 Then
            ActiveCell.offset(0, 0).Value = 0
            ActiveCell.offset(1, 0).Select


        End If



    Loop
End Sub

Comment: So that is my code. On a side note do I need to put the "`" in front of every line of code to code tag it or just the first line and last?

Comment: I forgot to put my sheet example:

Comment: 'Bank# Cue#
10 1
10 2
10 3
10 4
10 5
10 6
10 7
10 8
10 9
10 10
10 11
10 12
10 13
10 14
10 15
10 16
10 17
10 18
10 19
10 20
10 21
10 22
10 23
10 24
10 25
10 26
10 27
10 28
10 29
10 30
10 31
10 32
11 1
11 2
11 3
11 4
11 5
11 6
11 7
11 8
11 9
11 10
11 11
11 12
11 13
11 14
11 15
11 16
11 17
12 1
12 2
12 3
12 4
12 5
12 6
12 7
12 8
12 9
12 10
12 11
12 12
12 13
12 14
12 15
12 16
12 17
12 18
12 19
12 20
12 21
12 22
12 23
12 24
12 25
12 26
12 27
12 28
12 29
12 30
12 31
12 32
21 1
21 2
21 3
21 4
21 5
21 6
21 7
21 8
21 9'

Comment: after my code I get `Bank# Cue#
9 0
9 1
9 2
9 3
9 4
9 5
9 6
9 7
9 8
9 9
9 10
9 11
9 12
9 13
9 14
9 15
9 0
9 1
9 2
9 3
9 4
9 5
9 6
9 7
9 8
9 9
9 10
9 11
9 12
9 13
9 14
9 15
10 0
10 1
10 2
10 3
10 4
10 5
10 6
10 7
10 8
10 9
10 10
10 11
10 12
10 13
10 14
10 15
10 0
11 0
11 1
11 2
11 3
11 4
11 5
11 6
11 7
11 8
11 9
11 10
11 11
11 12
11 13
11 14
11 15
11 0
11 1
11 2
11 3
11 4
11 5
11 6
11 7
11 8
11 9
11 10
11 11
11 12
11 13
11 14
11 15
20 0
20 1
20 2
20 3
20 4
20 5
20 6
20 7
20 8
`

Comment: so the actualproblem is I cannot have TWO sequences the same EVER, so when the (second set of 9-0 shows up it should make it 10-0, but then the 10-0 later will have to move up also.

Comment: OK this is much clearer now - I think I understand your problem. I have edited my code so it actually runs now - doesn't yet take into account all the things you describe, that is quite a bit more complex. Can't spend the time tonight... maybe tomorrow.

Comment: I have created a new answer. I think it's what you want.

Comment: OK did you post it? and have I missed it.

Comment: Yes - there are now two answers to your question. The "good one" is the other answer...